# Не срабатывает clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, cleartimeout

Есть некий код:

```
var timer;
var actions = {
    start: function() {
        var self = this;
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            var $preloader = $("<div class='preloader-overlay'><div class='loader'></div></div>");
            self.append($preloader);
        }, 1000);
    },

    stop: function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        if (this.find('.preloader-overlay')!=undefined){
            this.find('.preloader-overlay').remove();
        }
    }
};
```

При старте загрузки страницы вызывается

```
actions.start();
```

Через 0.5 секунды вызывается

```
actions.stop();
```

То есть, по идее, вызов первой функции должен был удалиться. Но она все равно вызывается. Что я сделал не правильно?

Comment: а как вы через `0.5` секунд вызываете `actions.stop`?

Comment: это я примерно сказал, но суть в том что вызывается первая функция, потом подгрузка некоторого контента и потом вызов второй функции. подгрузка контента занимает менее секунды

Comment: вы в этом уверены? как вы проверили? как замеряли время?

Comment: в функции actions.stop() сделал вызов console.log(1); еденица выводится и после этого срабатывает первая функция

Comment: Ну вот, смотрите: https://jsfiddle.net/puhy0v6s/2/ — если достаточно быстро нажимать Stop после Start, то никакая функция не запускается и никакого `timer!!!` в консоли не печатается

Answer (score 0):

```js
let actions = {
  timer: null,
  start: function() {
    actions.timer = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('hi');
    }, 1000);
  },

  stop: function() {
    clearTimeout(actions.timer);
  }

};

actions.start();
actions.stop();
```

Answer (score -1):

убедись что timer существует в stop

```
console.log(timer);
alert(timer);
```